# $a^{100}-1$ is divisible by $1000$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

While working on competition math, I came upon the following problem:
How many integers $x$ from $1$ to $1000$ are there such that $x^{100}-1$ is divisible by $1000$?
This was very confusing, as the numbers that I had to deal with were so large, so I thought of using mods.
Here is what I did:
$$\begin{array}{l}
x^{100}-1\equiv 0 \mod 1000\\
x^{100}\equiv 1 \mod 1000
\end{array}
$$
From this, we are basically trying to find number of $x$'s such that $x^{100}$ ends in $0001$.
How should I proceed to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, the solutions of $x^{100} \equiv 1 \bmod 1000$ are exactly the solutions of the system
$$
x^{100} \equiv 1 \bmod 8,
\qquad  
x^{100} \equiv 1 \bmod 125 
$$
Now, $100$ is a multiple of both $\phi(8)=4$ and $\phi(125)=100$ and so all numbers that are coprime with both $8$ and $125$ are solutions of this system.

Therefore, the solutions of $x^{100} \equiv 1 \bmod 1000$ are exactly the numbers coprime with $1000$. There are $\phi(1000)=400$ solutions in $[1,1000]$.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I didn't think of using the CR, but I guess it helps to simplify this a lot!

Comment: @RK01, note how Euler's theorem does *not* help for $1000$. You need [Carmichael's $\lambda$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) instead of Euler $\phi$.